# Access each open browser window using WatiN

Tags: .net, watin

I can't see a way to simply loop through each open browser window in WatiN, only attach by xyz, which attaches to the first instance.

Basically I have multiple windows with the same url so I need to get these windows and then check page content for each before I can continue using the correct one.

Is this possible or does WatiN only ever return the first window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for example IECollection

Here is sample :

```
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {                        
        IE _ie = new IE("http://google.com");
        IE _ie2 = new IE("http://google.com");
        IE _ie3 = new IE("http://google.com");
        IE _ie4 = new IE("http://google.com");
        Debug.WriteLine(IE.InternetExplorers().Count);

        IECollection ies = new IECollection();
        foreach (var browser in ies)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(browser.Url.ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine(browser.hWnd);
            IE browser2 = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.By("hwnd", browser.hWnd.ToString()));
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            browser2.BringToFront();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good find, not much documentation regarding Watin.Core.IECollection out there. I managed to do it without WatiN using SHDocVw.ShellWindows shellWindows = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows(); but your solution is better.